# How to fix Cannot read property 'node' of undefined?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Tried to move from react 15.6.1 to react 16.8.5 in existing project and got such error: 
[image]

I thought it could be caused by propTypes, so I deleted code with propTypes from everywhere. However it did not help.

My webpack config:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:5050',
    // 'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    // 'react-hot-loader/patch',
    './index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.css'],
    alias: { 'react/lib/ReactMount': 'react-dom/lib/ReactMount' }
  },
  plugins: [
    // new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    // new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: ['babel-loader'],
      // loaders: ['react-hot-loader', 'babel-loader'],
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      include: __dirname
    },
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: [
          'style', 'css',
        ],
    },
    {
      test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg|gif)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
      loaders: ['url']
    }

    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
};
```

Here is link to the repo ;[Github](https://github.com/kkseven07/aresproj)

ReduxRouter error code:

```
var ReduxRouter = (function (_Component) {
  _inherits(ReduxRouter, _Component);

  _createClass(ReduxRouter, null, [{
    key: 'propTypes',
    value: {
      **children: _react.PropTypes.node**
    },
    enumerable: true
  }, {
    key: 'contextTypes',
    value: {
      store: _react.PropTypes.object
    },
    enumerable: true
  }]);
```

Comment: propTypes only show warnings if there is no typo

Comment: Also, `cannot read property node of undefined` happens when you have a variable `x` and you try to read `x.node` but `x` is undefined, so the error comes up. Are you doing somethings like this in your code, maybe in the ReduxRouter? If yes, please provide the code, maybe it's an error in your code and not webpack. If not, and you think the problem is in webpack, please provide your webpack configs.

Comment: Added webpack config. In react 15 version everything worked fine

Comment: `Tried to move from react 15.6.1 to react 16.8.5 ` what you did?

Comment: Just updated react and react dom versions

Comment: please share gitrepo url to your codebase

Comment: https://github.com/kkseven07/aresproj

Answer (score 0):

Have the same error after upgrade from 17.0.2 to 18.2.0, run with command

> rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && react-scripts build && gulp licenses

and the error is gone!